# Disable BIOS after POST, from OS

Tags: windows, bios, post

I don't really know if this is the right website to post this question, but here it goes (TL;DR highlighted):

It actually starts with a funny story which is needed for me to tell in case there are any misunderstandings. A good friend of mine met somebody in an online game, and that somebody managed to infect him with some kind of custom-coded virus. My friend called me for help, and when I arrived I discovered that he was being controlled remotely from the attacker's computer, who had full control over my friend's network.

Anyway, after being able to control the computer and whatnot, he uploaded many programs (most likely written by him) and he had the ability to hear what was going on in the room (through my friend's phone, but that's another story). He also started sending messages to my friend's Skype. When I mentioned *BIOS*, he had sent a message saying that he disabled it and there's no way of me getting back into it.

---

So I tried, turned off the PC, turned it on and ***started spamming F2, F10, F12, Delete, Tab, and many other buttons which I have knowledge of that could open up the BIOS. It did not show up, then I started the computer again, and it booted into Windows after a few seconds of black screen***. I had to stop the computer, ***reset the CMOS and then I actually managed to get into the BIOS***, but ***after booting into Windows AGAIN, the BIOS went missing AGAIN***, which led me to believe he placed an executable file in the Startup folder, or made it run whenever Windows got booted up—I was not connected to the Internet (or to the network, in fact) since the point when I discovered the BIOS was not working.

---

### ACTUAL QUESTION:

**Now, I was very surprised that this is possible, and if I were you I would not believe it myself if I were to read it in a random question on the Internet. But I really have to ask somebody, *how is disabing the BIOS from the Operating System possible? Or if not specific enough, how is it possible to disable the BIOS after POST?***

### EDIT NOTES:

I tried highlighting the important parts for a TL;DR. As I said, I would not blame you for not believing this, and I really hope this question will not get closed for an improper format.

Comment: I'm going to guess no, this is not caused by the malware, but by the OEM trying to make boot seamless. It is possible, albeit it unlikely, that the attacker flashed a bad bios, but that really is unlikely. to remedy that, you would download a BIOS flash from a trusted location on another device, and use USB to flash the affected system while it is detached from the network. Then back up content (but NO executables), format, and rebuild.

Comment: It's possible (Google BIOS malware for examples).  In the same way that you can update your BIOS from Windows, it is also possible to update the BIOS with a hacked version that would keep someone out of it and infect the boot record.

Comment: ^ This. Also it's entirely possible that the attacker flashed a corrupted BIOS firmware which disables shortcut keys to bios.

Comment: "he had sent a message saying that he disabled it and there's no way of me getting back into it." - NOT POSSIBLE.  What is possible is to password protect it.   Hardware that comes with Windows 8+, require you to use Advanced Startup, to acces the BIOS.  You were just trying to access the BIOS in the incorrect way.  Your story isn't really relevant IMO

Answer (score 0):

Nothing could have disabled BIOS in any way as your computer would not function.  The BIOS does a lot more than perform Power-On Self-Tests (POST). ([See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) for more information)

If the computer is running Windows 8, 8.1 or 10, accessing BIOS setttings is done differently to previous ways.

One of the most played-up features of Windows 8 is that it's so much faster than previous versions. So fast, in fact, that Microsoft had to change the way that users access the BIOS because 200 milliseconds just isn't enough time to hit the right key.  This continued into Windows 10.

**To access BIOS settings on Windows 8 and 8.1 computers**, you must follow these steps.

1. Open **Settings**
2. Select **General**
3. Under **Advanced Startup** click **Restart Now**
4. The computer will restart into the Boot Menu where you need to click on the **Troubleshoot** icon
5. Then click UEFI Firmware Settings

**To access BIOS settings on Windows 10 computers**, you must follow these steps.

1. Navigate to settings. ...
2. Select Update & security.
3. Select Recovery from the left menu.
4. Click Restart Now under Advanced startup. ...
5. Click Troubleshoot.
6. Click Advanced options.
7. Select UEFI Firmware Settings.
8. Click Restart.